# How to create a font alias in Windows 7 or in Outlook

Tags: windows-7, fonts, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a work colleague that uses OCR A Extended as the preferred font for his outgoing emails. It is difficult for me to read his emails.
Is there any way to create an alias in Outlook 2010 or Windows 7 for whatever is received with font OCR A Extended to be shown with a more preferred font?   I still require this font from time to time for my work.

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, Outlook doesn’t have such a built-in option to change the font for incoming messages. As a workaround, you can switch message format to plain text to read this kind of message.

To do this, double click to open the email and click Message tab > Actions > Edit Message. Under Format Text, Choose Plain Text as the format.

If you have more concerns on this feature, it is encouraged to visit the Outlook user voice forum: https://outlook.uservoice.com/ to vote for a similar idea or post your own.